# Regex IsMatch centered at specific index of string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a problem in speed of this part of code:

```
string sl = text.Substring(0, i);
string sr = text.Substring(i);
var l = left.IsMatch(sl);//with $ at end of regex
var r = right.IsMatch(sr);//with ^ at begin of regex
bool answer = l && r;
```

This is just function that checks context of specific place of the string. Calling `Substring` here is a very expensive operation, so I decided to look for some other way of doing this.

```
reg.IsMatch(text,i);
```

This method is only good for `sr` substring of this text (from `i` to the end of the string).

Is there any way to `IsMatch` my `sl` without having to call `Substring` (from 0 to `i`)? For example, like this:

```
reg.IsMatch(text,0,i);
```

So the question is, how can I regex a specific part of the string (from `i` position to `j` position)?

Comment: How do you determine the value of `i`?

Comment: I find it very surprising that `Substring` is an expensive operation. Are you sure that's really the slow part?

Comment: Yes it is. I have 10 mb/second flow of text files, and need to do some heuristic pre-analyze that data. Getting substring of whole 10mb text in two direction is memory apocalipsis in many threads. Index `i` I get from another, unrelated part of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you review the [`IsMatch` method overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch.aspx), you'll that there is only one method with similar behaviour you need:

> [`IsMatch(String, Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1hx7a5y.aspx)
>   Indicates whether the regular expression specified in the Regex constructor finds a match in the specified input string, beginning at the specified starting position in the string.

But this method is solving only a part of your problem, so you'll have to use [`Match` overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match.aspx):

> [`Match(String, Int32, Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h09aybcd.aspx)
>   Searches the input string for the first occurrence of a regular expression, beginning at the specified starting position and searching only the specified number of characters.

You should note that this method returns [`Match`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.aspx) object, so you have to examine it.
So your code will be something like this (you should check the indexes):

```
var l = left.Match(text, 0, i);//with $ at end of regex
var r = right.Match(text, i + 1, text.Length - 1 - i);//with ^ at begin of regex
bool answer = l.Success && r.Success;
```

Comment: You are the perfomance saver! I didn't even knew about this function...Thank you!

Comment: I tried, but it said that for these I need to get 15 reputation ) hope I don't forget when I get there )